# Compare two files and get the matching rows based on two columns

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, command-line, files

I have two pipe delimited file like below

**file1.txt**

```
A1234|JESSIE|OPTED
A1224|JOHN|OPTED
L1212|RAMSAY|OPTED
L1832|TIZEN|TESTED
```

**file2.txt**

```
A1234|B1465
G1211|L1211
G1241|L1212
G1271|L1232
```

**Desired output**

```
A1234|B1465
G1241|L1212
```

I am trying to compare column 1 and column 2 in file2.txt with column 1 in file1.txt and get the matching rows in file2.txt if it the first column in file1.txt matches with either column 1 or column 2 in file2.txt.

I tried the awk below but it doesn't appear to be giving me the right results.

```
awk -F'|' 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=1; next} a[$1,2]' file1.txt file2.txt > output.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk -F '|' 'NR==FNR{a[$1]; next} ($1 in a) || ($2 in a)' file1.txt file2.txt
A1234|B1465
G1241|L1212
```